AWS Glue Crawler misinterpreting gzip CSV file location,

The issue that I am facing is that when I am running the crawler to read the gzip file it is able to get the schema of the CSV file. But the thing is when I am running the query on athena to preview the table I am not getting the data in the csv file.
Another thing that I observed is that when I am seeing the details of the table in aws glue I can observe that the location is pointing towards the folder that has the name of the file instead of the file and the folder doesn't exist.
Is it doing this because it has a problem in reading compressed files? If that is the case should I do something with the classifier?
I feel like maybe I have to create a custom classifier I'm not sure.
